# PROBLEMA CON AL LETRA Ñ AL OBTENER TOKEN DESDE ANGULAR

Tags: angular, utf-8

Estoy conectándome desde angular a un servidor apirest para obtener token, en el payload del token viene los datos del usuario entonces pasa que el apellido del usuario contiene una letra ñ y en la respuesta viene malformada.

tratae de enviar en la cabecera el `'charset': 'utf-8'`
pero aun asi no funciona.

éste es el código de petición:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Usuario } from './usuario';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(usuario:Usuario):Observable<any>{

    const urlEndPoint = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token";
    const credenciales = btoa("angularapp"+':'+'12345');
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
                                         'Authorization': 'Basic '+ credenciales, 'charset': 'utf-8'});

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('grant_type','password');
    params.set('username', usuario.username);
    params.set('password',usuario.password);

    // console.log("params.toString(): ", params.toString());
    // console.log("params: ", params);

    return this.http.post<any>(urlEndPoint, params.toString(), {headers: httpHeaders});

  }
}
```

Y ésta es la respuesta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Verifica la configuración, si tu API o tu DB estén bien... el origen de tu problema no necesariamente tiene que ser de tu proyecto angular

Comment: Como te han dicho, el problema puede venir que el API esté recogiendo un valor mal formado, porque en la base de datos no se guarde el utf-8, primero habría que comprobar cómo está guardado en la BBDD, después comprobar antes de generar el token qué valor se está introduciendo desde el back.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré fue ésta.

usar un script para decodificar el token pero que resuelva las letras especiales.

```
  obtenerDatosToken(accessToken:string):any{
    if (accessToken != null) {

      return JSON.parse(this.decode(atob(accessToken.split('.')[1])));

    }else{
      return null;
    }
  }


  /**
   * 
   * @param utftext 
   * 
   * string =  cigueÃ±a nÃºmeros
   * La funcion decode(string) da como resultado cigueña números
   */
  decode(utftext){
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = 0;
    var c1 = 0;
    var c2 = 0;
    var c3 = 0;

    while (i < utftext.length) {

        c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

        if (c < 128) {
            string += String.fromCharCode(c);
            i++;
        }
        else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
            i += 2;
        }
        else {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
            i += 3;
        }

    }

    return string;
  }
```